# Cassandra failure during write query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM

Tags: java, file, cassandra, load

While I am writing xml file into Cassandra table column  I am facing following exception.Its a 3 node cluster and All nodes are up.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteFailureException: Cassandra failure during write query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteFailureException.copy(WriteFailureException.java:80)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:55)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:39)
    at DBConnection.oracle2Cassandra(DBConnection.java:267)
    at DBConnection.main(DBConnection.java:292)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteFailureException: Cassandra failure during write query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteFailureException.copy(WriteFailureException.java:91)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:119)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:180)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:186)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2300(RequestHandler.java:44)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:754)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:576)
```

It would be great if someone helps me out from this situation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

However i don't know real solutions.

One of the cluster node var/log/cassandra/system.log file. I found sstable corrupted for a table. The table is used in code from where its throwing exception.

Take backups of table.
Removed corrupted db file from node.
Drop table.
Re-create table.

It's work for me.